# FB Connect and No data appears

Tags: php, facebook

I have implemented FB connect on a site for the users to take a quiz:

The quiz can be accessed at this page:

http://www.dirtytalk101.com/take-quiz/

Now I am witnessing two problems:

1: When somebody clicks on FB connect button and logs in the dialog box doesn't close, rather it redirects to same page site's page on the very dialog box.

2: When we complete taking the quiz, and come back to homepage, there is no data on homepage and on most of the pages i receive 404 error. However, when i delete all cookies and then refresh the page, everything works fine with no errors but of course this is not a permanent solution, as i don't want users to delete their cookies after taking each quiz.

I have tried hard but without any luck. It would be greatly appreciated if you guys take your precious time and suggest me a solution or point the cause of the issues.

Thanks in advance ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see an "xd_receiver.htm" file in the location you specified in your init call:

```
FB.init("e2d8c3ba5ca35a90fa504c1e6bd1d39a", "xd_receiver.htm", {"ifUserConnected": "http://www.dirtytalk101.com/?e=quiz&qid=1"});

// should be here: http://www.dirtytalk101.com/take-quiz/xd_receiver.htm
```

Should be a file that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" > 
<body> 
    <script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/XdCommReceiver.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

This file is the "cross domain" (xd) communication file which Connect needs to "send" cookies and requests through.

Comment: can't wont dont have that much reputation :(